# Scala - Why a function returns Unit instead of an RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

When I've implemented the function I wanted it to return an RDD. And probably collect it to List later. But why does it return Unit instead? What should I change in the implementation to make it return an RDD?

Sales is a map (saleId, Saletype) - `val sales: Map[Int, String]`

```
val processSales: Unit = sales.foreach(sale => sc.makeRDD(salesService.getData(sale._1)))
```

Comment: What is the type of `sales` object ?

Comment: why don't you iterate with `map` function over an RDD?

Comment: It is a `Map[Int, String]`, sorry for missing this

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` returns `Unit`, You can see the return type as below

> def foreach(f: T => Unit): Unit =

Use `map` instead to return an `RDD`

> def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U] =